# Python library that can compute the confusion matrix for multi-label classification

Tags: python, software-recommendation, multilabel-classification

I'm looking for a Python library that can compute the [confusion matrix for multi-label classification](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/21551/12359).

---

FYI:

- scikit-learn [doesn't](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3452) support multi-label for confusion matrix)
- [What is the difference between Multiclass and Multilabel Problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/168945/12359)

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: @MortezaShahriariNia I stayed monolabeled.

Comment: what would a theoretical multilabel confusion matrix look like?  I do not think it applies, does it?

Comment: very funny that all 3 answers to this question are of such remarkably low quality.

Comment: Not aware of any packages, but you could perhaps consider all possible multi-label combination as a separate class and use some of the already-available packages for multi-class. Then, from that confusion, build your multi-label matrix

Comment: sci-kit learn now provides a multilabel confusion matrix: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.multilabel_confusion_matrix.html#sklearn.metrics.multilabel_confusion_matrix

Answer (score 3):

Also take a look at [scikit-multilearn](http://scikit.ml/). It is a very good library that extends sklearn for multi-label learning. However, I'm not sure how the confusion matrix works for multi-label problems...

This guy [claims](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25503260/build-confusion-matrix-for-multiclass-multilabel-classification) he has solved it.

Comment: skmultilearn has no confusion matrix utils.

Answer (score 2):

Although this question is old, I am writing this answer for new audience.

scikit-learn now supports confusion matrix for multi-label classification.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.multilabel_confusion_matrix.html

Answer (score 1):

Try [mlxtend](http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/). [Here](http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/evaluate/confusion_matrix/#example-2-multi-class-classification)'s an example of multi-class case.

[image]

Comment: how about multi-label multi-class? Is it supported?

Comment: No, this library does not support multi-label

Answer (score 1):

There are many different parameters which can evaluate the performance of your method by comparing the real and predicted labels. I suggest [PyCM](https://github.com/sepandhaghighi/pycm) module which can give a vast variety these parameters which are suitable for multi-class classification.

Comment: Does not support multi-label. https://github.com/sepandhaghighi/pycm/issues/211

Answer (score 0):

Sklearn has a method for it using which you can compute confusion matrix for multi class.

```
from sklearn import cross_validation
confusion_matrix(original, Predicted)
```

Comment: how about multi-label? https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3452 is still open

Answer (score 0):

Scikit-learn does support multi-label confusion matrix. See the links below for documentation and user guide:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#confusion-matrix

Comment: Thank you, that's why I am looking for an alternative option :-)

Answer (score 0):

Look at [sed_eval](https://github.com/TUT-ARG/sed_eval) library. It is developed for evaluating event detection in audio which is a multi-label problem (as in each audio, multiple events exist). They have many evaluation options, which might fit to your needs. 
You can get the true-positive rate, ... and from there computing the confusion matrix is not that hard.